# Spring Batch Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace error

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch job that fails immediately.  It runs in my Eclipse environment, and ran in production too.  But, with a new laptop, etc., am getting this error now which I don't have an answer for when I export it.

I use Maven to create an executable jar file.  It's run for years, but now  gets this error when running the java -jar... command.

I read this error can be caused by a missing jar.  I do have the spring-context jar in the POM... I don't know or fully understand this error.
xxxxxxx-launch-context.xml

How can you be missing a Spring jar when you're using Maven to build the executable?

I am not doing anything different I haven't always done (that I know of)
Thanks.

```
[INFO ]050319 104131 Failed. 'Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: class path resource [xxxxxxx-launch-context.xml]
' (Launcher.java:111)
```

Here's the spring-context jar inside the exe.

[image]

My pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <version>1.0.0-RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <target-java-version>1.8</target-java-version>
        <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
        <spring.framework.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <spring.batch.version>2.1.9.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>


 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>strict</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.test.failure.ignore>false</maven.test.failure.ignore>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>tiger</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>1.5</jdk>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                    <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.xml.stream</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- APACHE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MAIL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- GLAZERS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.glazers</groupId>
            <artifactId>gz-common-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>3.6.0</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        job configuration file
                        <argument>classpath:/comptroller-launch-context.xml</argument>
                        job name
                        <argument>job1</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Codehaus</id>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Please share your pom to see what could be missing.

Comment: Hi..... I added the pom.   Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Thanks for adding the pom. However, I still don't see what could be the reason of that error. `It's run for years, but now gets this error when running the java -jar... command.` If it run for years, what have you changed to have this error now?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine  .... Thanks for the reply... I will stay on it (obviously), and will return with what I find.   It's probably something simple....but the error is puzzling.  Thank you. MD

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine  after looking at older jars, I need to research having the pom put all the dependent jars in the root of the target jar.  I'll post search another question.  I upgraded lots of versions, and don't know if that somehow has changed the behavior of Maven...  I know it's a Maven class-path problem.  not a Spring Batch problem

Comment: ok thanks for the updates. I hope you will find and fix your issue. Good luck.